# User Profile Synchronization problem

Tags: user-profile, userprofile-sync

We have setup synchronization connection which connects to SQL via BCS. There are few user profile properties that are mapped to the attribute coming from BCS connection. This is all about the background information.

Now the actual issue: We recently added few more properties in SQL table . We updated the BCS model via SharePoint designer and deployed the same . When we trying to map the SharePoint user profile property to the attribute from the dropdown, the dropdown is still showing the old attributes and does not contain the newly added attributes. I verified my BCS model and it is showing the newly added properties. What do I need to do so that the dropdown shows the newly added attribute in BCS model. We have incremental sync set up in our environment and it is scheduled  to run daily. Please let me your thoughts on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the version number of your model? I suspect that the UPS is caching the old version of the model. You could try a reboot, but I suspect you will have to recreate the BCS connection to force the use of the new vesion of the model.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. How can I update the version number? I only have changed ETC in SPD. Recreate the connection is very bad for me, because there are many properties and I will should re-map all of them with user profile properties. It is a very big work :(

Comment: SPD is a VERY limited editor. It may have updated the model version. You can export the model and use Notepad++ or other editor to do a better job on the model file.

Comment: I checked, The ETC version was updated. In SPD was new version and in BCS was a new version. I also checked XML of ETC there are new version and new column, But dropdown is empty still.